# Нейросети - использование сигмоиды в методе обратного распространения - непонимание производных

Tags: математика, нейронные-сети

Я приблизительно понимаю, почему в работе с нейросетями используется сигмоида.
Но вот чего я не понимаю, так это почему призводная этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

равна этому:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а не этому:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Википедии написано "Производная сигмоиды может быть легко выражена через саму функцию". Если это является причиной такого вида производной, может ли кто-то пояснить, как и почему?

Comment: При подстановке самой функции (формула №1) во вторую формулу получается третья формула. Вторая формула - это и значит "выразить производную через саму функцию".

Comment: Пробовал, не работает так. Каша получается, а не формула. Я понимаю, что это больше к математике, чем к программированию, но отдельного stackoverflow под нее нет ( на русском)

Comment: Это работает, если все аккуратно свернуть и упростить.

Comment: В этом я и прошу помочь

Answer (score 6):

Элементарные преобразования. Правда, за отсутствием поддержки TeX приходится давать картинку...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

ещё один вывод :

```
sig(x) = 1/(1  +  e^-x)

sig'(x) = e^-x/(1  +  e^-x)^2 = 

= (1  +  e^-x  - 1)/(1  +  e^-x  -1)^2 =

= (1  +  e^-x  -1)/(1  +  e^-x  -1)^2 - 1/(1  +  e^-x  -1)^2 = 

= 1/(1  +  e^-x  -1)  -  1/(1  +  e^-x  -1)^2 = 

= sig(x) - sig^2(x) = sig(x)(1 - sig(x))
```